# Text showing behind buttons in css

Tags: html, css

I have a menu bar `header` at the top of my page.

My goal is to insert text (vertically-centered in the header) to the right of the buttons (which should be appear inline one after another) in a div called `live_stats`.

So far I have tried to add  `style='display:inline;` and also `inline-block` in both the css and html, but this does not appear to work. The text always appears behind the buttons, and always in the top lefthand corner.

What am I doing wrong in CSS? How would one create a div or give a class to a div that is directly adjacent to and inline with buttons to the left of it?   Any suggestions would be appreciated

In the javascript, there are dynamic variables added to the div simply with

```
document.getElementById("live_stats").innerHTML = "foo : " + bar.length + baz.length
```

This is what i've tried so far:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var ref = document.getElementById("live_stats").innerHTML = "foo : ";
};
```

```css
#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(12, 12, 12, 0.8);
  color: #eee;
  font: 16px/20px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  left: 8px;
  top: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#live_stats {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id='header'>
  <button id="buttonA" class='btn'></button>
  <button id="buttonB" class='btn'></button>
  <button id="buttonC" class='btn'></button>
  <div id="live_stats" style="display: inline;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your `HTML` there is no text! Not in the buttons, not next to the buttons, not outside the buttons.

Comment: Can you share the plunkr ?

Comment: In Jquery I use  `innerHTML` to define the text in the div "live_stats"

Comment: So you either also show us that code or you just type the text inside that `<div>` how it is what makes it broken. Or how do you think we can help you? And what is the expected output? Right now you layer 3 buttons one over the other, is that what you want?

Comment: I've added that

Comment: `#header {text-align: center;}` and `#live_stats: line height: 50px;`

Comment: the most important part is making sure the text is to the right of the buttons

Comment: The code is right there, it is complete, verifiable, and reproducible  - even with a snippet to make it clear!!  The expected behavior is clearly stated - to position a div with text to the right of buttons.  And I have stated what I have already tried.

Comment: So you want the text always just next to the button not centered horizontal .. just vertically next to button?

Comment: just vertically next to the button yes - centered vertically in the `#header`

Comment: @the_darkside because your .btn has `absolute` position. Give `absolute` position to your `"live_stats"` and adjust it

Comment: Absolute positioning takes the element out of the normal document flow, keep that in mind! it does not interact with the other elements!

Comment: @the_darkside don't play with `absolute` added with `margin`s if you don't understand the play, Its not a good idea generally!! :) . Use `float` instead : https://jsfiddle.net/hqcqLnp2/1/

Comment: thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `position:absolute`..I have changed some of your css...I will suggest to remove height from the `#header`..Use padding instead to adjust

***Stack Snippet***

```css
#header {
  background: rgba(12, 12, 12, 0.8);
  color: #eee;
  font: 16px/20px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#live_stats {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='header'>
  <button id="buttonA" class='btn'></button>
  <button id="buttonB" class='btn'></button>
  <button id="buttonC" class='btn'></button>
  <div id="live_stats">stats</div>
</div>
```